# How can I print all the elements of a vector in a single string in R?

Tags: r, string-concatenation

Sometimes I want to print all of the elements in a vector in a single string, but it still prints the elements separately:

```
notes <- c("do","re","mi")
print(paste("The first three notes are: ", notes,sep="\t"))
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "The first three notes are: \tdo" "The first three notes are: \tre"
[3] "The first three notes are: \tmi"
```

What I really want is:

```
The first three notes are:      do      re      mi
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The simplest way might be to *combine* your message and data using one `c` function:

```
paste(c("The first three notes are: ", notes), collapse=" ")
### [1] "The first three notes are:  do re mi"
```

Comment: `collapse` instead of `sep` does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The `cat` function both con**cat**enates the elements of the vector and prints them:

```
cat("The first three notes are: ", notes,"\n",sep="\t")
```

Which gives:

```
The first three notes are:      do      re      mi
```

The `sep` argument allows you to specify a separating character (e.g. here `\t` for tab). Also, Adding a newline character (i.e. `\n`) at the end is also recommended if you have any other output or a command prompt afterwards.

Comment: also, `paste(..., collapse="\t")`

Comment: Also important to note that `cat` is really _only_ good for displaying output to the user; the function only ever returns `NULL` invisibly. If you want to capture the result, you'll need to use `paste`.

Comment: @BrodieG In this case, that would be `paste(c("The first three notes are: ", notes,"\n"),collapse="\t")`. Thanks!

Comment: @joran Very true. Here's how to capture the result for this scenario: `result <- paste(c("The first three notes are: ", notes,"\n"),collapse="\t")`. Thanks!